# Does assert.equal offer any advantages over assert (assert.ok)?

Tags: node.js, assert

In this question I refer to the [assert](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) module that is included within the node.js core.

As far as I can tell the following two assertions are pretty much identical:

```
assert.equal(typeof path, "string", "argument 'path' must be a string");
assert(typeof path === "string", "argument 'path' must be a string");
```

Upon failure both variations report the same message:

```
AssertionError: argument 'path' must be a string
```

Are there any notable advantages of the former over the latter in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, depending on the test runner framework, `assert.equal` will probably give you a more descriptive error message. For instance, in this case:

```
assert.equal(typeof path, "string");
assert(typeof path === "string");
```

the first statement would give you a message along the lines of:

```
actual: number
expected: string
```

which already tells you that the test case fails because `typeof path` is a `number`.
The latter will only print something like this:

```
AssertionError: false == true
```

Also, note that if you want to check for strict equality (===), you should use `assert.strictEqual` instead of `assert.equal`.

Answer (score 1):

`assert.equal` doesn't check for identity, only equality. It's equivalent to:

```
assert(typeof path == 'string', "argument 'path' must be a string");
```

The real equivalent would be `assert.strictEqual`, which uses the identity operator `===`:

```
assert.strictEqual(typeof path, "string", "argument 'path' must be a string");
```

For `typeof`, no, there's no difference. You'll run into problems with other data types though:

```
> assert.equal('test', ['test']);
undefined
> 'test' == ['test']
true
> 'test' === ['test']
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Both will work.

First, `assert` uses the **coercive** `==` operator, not **strict** `===`

Also, when you read a lot of your unit tests or other people's unit tests, you'll strain your eyes on repetitive syntax. You'll love it when people will write this

```
assert.equal(aValue, anotherValue) // sexy

/** But you will hate people writing this. **/
assert.ok(aValue == anotherValue) // ugly
```

In the first case, you can see the condition being checked within the first 9 letters. You don't even need to look *further*. In the other case, you have to read 20 letters to know what the test is checking. It's more **cryptic**.

Also, `assert.equal` is more declarative of your intention than assert.ok.

Imagine you are writing a test for testing a set intersection. You would read better

```
assert.setIntersect(set1, set2) // wow

assert.ok(setIntersect(set1, set2)); // hm.
```

To sum it up, the advantage is in readability (thus maintainability) of you unit tests. It's not much, but it helps writing better understandable code.

As alexander said, too, you will have more precise error messages when test fail if you don't specify a message.

Comment: *co·er·cive* relating to or using force or threats.

Comment: Yeah, forcing that **integer** into that **string**.

Comment: 1 == '1' // true; 1 === '1' // false. integer was **coerced** to string